# Can't create files Heroku Cedar-14

Tags: php, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So I have an application

```
  + Application Folder
  |
   --- index.php
   --- folder 1
   --- folder 2
```

I want to create a data folder outside this 'Application folder'.

Problem: If I go 1 up in the tree and try to do a git push, heroku doesn't let me

```
+ 1 up from application folder
  |
  + --- Application Folder
  + --- Data folder
```

And I can't ssh into the box and create a folder because it tells me it's a read only file system.

FYI: The dashboard app settings say it's on cedar 14. And I'm running on a free account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you SSH in somewhere, that would be an isolated instance. Imagine scaling from 1 to 100 dynos and then making a filesystem modification on one of them, how should that work in terms of syncing etc?

I assume you want to add files outside of where `index.php` lives, so you basically want to change the document root for the project to a subdirectory.

Your "+1 up from application folder" is then the Git project root, and your application folder is the document root. Create a `Procfile` as instructed here to set the document root to your application folder: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root

You do realize however that anything you write into the data folder on a dyno will not be available on your local computer, right? You can't "download" it, it's a Git repo. The data you write on one dyno also will not be available on other dynos (e.g. when you `heroku ps:scale web=10` to have ten dynos), and every time you scale up or down, `git push`, or just after around 24 hours (when dynos auto restart), any changes to the local filesystem will be gone.

Comment: Thank you. 
Yes, it wouldn't make sense to change things on a machine, but since I am just testing the waters this should be fine.
Understood. I did read that the file system is "ephemeral" So I have set up a cron that will back up the testing data for reuse/analysis.