# Heroku : Sync file from heroku to local

Tags: heroku, laravel-5, heroku-toolbelt

This may look like an stupid question, but i didn't find any answer to my question.

I recently do in the Heroku Bash : `php artisan make:controller user/edit`.

It's now there, in the cloud, but not in my computer. Please note that is not just with `make:controller` but it can be with anything.

For example, pull a databse is easy, `heroku db:pull`. But how to pull file?

I tried with `git pull`, and I get an `Already up-to-date.` answer.

I can't play with files, and this is not awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, and that's intentional. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463836/162354 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28083271/162354 for answers to the same question.

You run stuff like `php artisan make:controller user/edit` on your local computer, test it there, and when stuff works, you push it up. That's the correct workflow. Heroku is not a development sandbox.

Comment: Thanks. I chose Heroku because Laravel is not working fine in my computer. Another Windows related capacities. I will tried it out

Comment: Install a virtual machine with Linux, or buy a Mac :)

Comment: I try Vagrant with PuPHPet but it doesn't install apache2 even if it is on my config file. Mac is pretty expensive for my budget of student, but It's can be awesome.